# Creating a circle with radius in metres

Tags: python, area, shapely, units

I am using shapely and Python.

How should I go about creating a circle using shapely whose radius is in meters?

If i use

```py
sampleCircle = Point(1,1).buffer(1)
print(sampleCircle.area)
```

This returns an area of 3.13654849055. How do I interpret the unit of this area? I read that this can be interpreted in square degrees but seek a little more explanation.

Also, how do I create a circle with a specified radius (in meters) around a point (defined using lat,long)?

The closest article I found was this http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.gis/1582 but it lacks any concrete solution

Answer (score 19):

By design Shapely is unaware of [coordinate reference systems or units](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#coordinate-systems). To use it to solve real world problems, you must learn to transform longitude and latitude to an approximately planar local reference system (like a US State Plane) and you must keep track of your own units. I use pyproj to do this, but you can use whatever you want. Once you've transformed your long and lat degrees to x and y meters, `Point(x, y).buffer(1.0).area` is the area in m^2 of your circle (64-sided polygon to be precise).

Answer (score 6):

Based on the link you provided (almost all work is done there), you can get a polygon representing that circle (64-side polygon).

```
from functools import partial

import pyproj
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform

lon, lat = -122.431297, 37.773972 # lon lat for San Francisco
radius = 10000  # in m

local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(
    lat, lon
)
wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"),
    pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
)
aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
    pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"),
)

center = Point(float(lon), float(lat))
point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, center)
buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius)
# Get the polygon with lat lon coordinates
circle_poly = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the `resolution` argument in the `.buffer()`-method. Resolution defaults to 16, and this creates a 64 sided polygon. Why?

Comment: The `+R=6371000` parameter in the local azimuthal projection gave me incoherent results when combined with a geodesic distance function. Omitting the parameter makes the projection default to "GRS-80" and gave me expected results. Note: I did not plot near San Francisco.