# Performance problem with getting average pixel values within buffered circles

Tags: python, performance, rasterio, numpy

I have a EPSG:4326 raster file with pixel size of 15 arcseconds, and a list of longitudes and latitudes. For each pair of coordinate, I want to create a buffered circle of X kilometers surrounding them, and aggregate over the pixel values within each circle.

Following this thread: [Rasterio. Pixel value of a point X km away from current point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/421233/199094):

1. I have used Shapely to get a circle of defined radius from a centre point (after reprojecting the EPSG:4326 file to a projected coordinate system).
2. Then, I use `rasterio.features.geometry_mask` to calculate a numpy mask given the Shapely circle.
3. Finally, I calculate the average pixel value on the masked array with `np.ma.mean`

The problem is the `np.ma.mean` function is too slow for my numpy array (it has the shape of `(34779, 45217)`, and dtype of `float32`), and it can take hours to perform the operation over my list of 5000 longtitudes and latitudes. Is there any other way? I am open to any tool, including Python, R, and any and all software.

Below is the annotated code for your reference.

```python
from functools import partial
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform
from rasterio.features import geometry_mask
import rasterio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


sample = pd.read_csv(lat_lon_url) # read in dataframe that contains longtitude and latitude
raster = rasterio.open(raster_url)
band = raster.read(1)

''' 
apply the get_mean function for each row of the sample dataframe.
each row of the sample dataframe has a longitude and latitude. 
'''
sample['lightscore'] = sample.apply(lambda row: get_mean(row['longtitude'], row['latitude'], 
                                    raster.height, raster.width, raster.transform, 
                                    band, radius = 5000), axis = 1)
```

Below is the `get_mean` function.

```python
'''
get_mean function 
1. creates a circle with specified radius surrounding the point with longitude & latitude
2. aggregate over the circle to get average pixel value
'''

def get_mean(lon, lat,
             raster_height, raster_width, raster_transform,
             band, radius: float) -> float:

    '''
    Define the projected and geographic coordinate system
    '''
    local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(
        lat, lon
    )
    wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

    '''
    Define the projection.
    '''
    wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(wgs84),
        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
    )
    aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
        pyproj.Proj(wgs84),
    )


    center = Point(float(lon), float(lat))
    point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, center) # reproject the point from geographic to projected system
    buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius)
    circle_poly = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer) # reproject the buffered circle from projected back to geographic system

    '''
    Calculate a numpy mask given the Shapely circle.
    '''
    circle_mask = geometry_mask(geometries = [circle_poly], 
                                out_shape = (raster_height, raster_width),
                                transform = raster_transform) # this takes a while for each record of my sample dataframe,
                                                              # but not as long as the np.ma.mean below               

    '''
    Create masked numpy array and aggregate over it
    '''                                            
    masked_data = np.ma.array(band, mask=circle_mask)
    mean = masked_data.mean() # this takes EXTREMELY LONG for each record of my sample dataframe.

    return mean
```

Comment: Intuitively, I think that running `mean` on a `np.ma.array` should be quite fast. What is the shape and dtype of your array?

Comment: @StefanBrand I have updated my question to include the shape and dtype of my numpy array. Its shape is `(34779, 45217)`, and the dtype is `float32`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your array has a size of ~6 GiB: `GiB = 34779 * 45217 * 32 / 8 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024`. Trying to allocate a random numpy array of this shape crashes here.

Comment: I'd probably generate a geodata file for all circles and then use [`rasterstats`](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats) or even QGIS to do the zonal statistics for me. They are surely better suited for such large datasets than looping with numpy.

Comment: @StefanBrand I have not used these tools, but from your text, I assume that QGIS is more suitable for larger datasets compared to ```rasterstats```, and both of them are definitely better than ```numpy```?

Comment: I cannot comment on whether they are _definitely_ better. It's just a gut-feeling. Try it out :) [QGIS 3.22 Zonal Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=zonal%20stats#zonal-statistics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQGIS manages to perform this task significantly faster than `numpy` or `rasterstats`. Here is the link to the cookbook: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html.

To complete the task:

> ... a EPSG:4326 raster file with pixel size of 15 arcseconds, and a list of longitudes and latitudes. For each pair of coordinate, ... create a buffered circle of X kilometers surrounding them, and aggregate over the pixel values within each circle.

You can use the below template:

```python
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

import pandas as pd

# Inits app
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(path_to_qgis, True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Sets up original CRS
epsg4326 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
transformContext = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()

# Creates shapefile to write buffer into
filename = "buffers.shp"

fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField(lon_col_name, QVariant.Double))
fields.append(QgsField(lat_col_name, QVariant.Double))

save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
save_options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
save_options.fileEncoding = "UTF-8"

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(
    filename, 
    fields,
    QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,
    epsg4326,
    transformContext,
    save_options
)

# Loads .csv file as vector layer
data_url = "link/to/csv/file/contains/lat/lon"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(data_url, "coordinates", "ogr")
features = vlayer.getFeatures()

field_names = [ field.name() for field in vlayer.fields() ]
lat_col_idx = field_names.index("lat")
lon_col_idx = field_names.index("lon")

for f in features: # each feature is a point
    attributes = f.attributes()
    lat = float(attributes[lat_col_idx])
    lon = float(attributes[lon_col_idx])

    # Sets up projected CRS and transformer
    local_azimuthal = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
    proj4_str = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(lat, lon)
    local_azimuthal.createFromProj(proj4_str)

    wgs84_to_azimuthal = QgsCoordinateTransform(epsg4326, local_azimuthal, transformContext)
    azimuthal_to_wgs84 = QgsCoordinateTransform(local_azimuthal, epsg4326, transformContext)

    # Projects the point, creates buffer, and reprojects to original CRS
    projected_point = wgs84_to_azimuthal.transform(QgsPointXY(lon, lat))
    point_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(projected_point)
    radius = 5000 # in meters
    segment = 18
    buffer = point_geom.buffer(radius, segment)
    buffer.transform(azimuthal_to_wgs84)

    # Writes buffer to file
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry(buffer)
    fet.setAttributes([lon, lat])
    writer.addFeature(fet)

# flush file to avoid memory leak
del writer

# Reads in the buffer shape files
filename = "buffers.shp"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, "buffers", "ogr")

# Calculates zonal mean-s for each raster
raster_url = "link/to/raster"
raster = QgsRasterLayer(raster_url)
zoneStats = QgsZonalStatistics(vlayer, raster, stats = QgsZonalStatistics.Statistics(QgsZonalStatistics.Mean))
zoneStats.calculateStatistics(None)

# Writes zonal mean-s to csv
destUrl = "link/to/destination/csv"
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "CSV"
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(vlayer, destUrl, transformContext, options)

del vlayer
```

Thank you @StefanBrand for suggesting QGIS.